# Obtaining the sum of a series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

***Given the following example:***

Obtain the Sum of the series
$$\frac{1}{(2)(4)}+\frac{1}{(4)(6)}+\frac{1}{(6)(8)}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)2(n+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{4k(k+1)}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}$$
**Solution**: Resolve
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$
into partial fractions to get
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
S_n&=\frac{1}{4}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+1}\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left[1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\frac{n}{n+1}
\end{align}$$

***My questions then are:**

 1. How do we get $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$. Where does the minus come from?

 2. How can we simplifi $\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ to be equal to $1$? I get that if n tends to infinity that $\frac{1}{n}$ would become effectively 0, but what about the initial big fractions? They are very much bigger than 1 if you add even just a few of them together.

 3. How do we go from the second last line to the last line? What happens to the minus sign? Where does the n in the numerator come from?*

Comment: Let's start with the last one. Do you know how to combine $1-{1\over n+1}$ into a single fraction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As the solution states, you get that expansion by using the method of partial fractions. There are many websites that [cover this topic](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx), but here you may want to just verify the identity:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1} &= \frac{k+1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{k}{k(k+1)} \\
                          &= \frac{k+1-k}{k(k+1)} \\
                          &= \frac{1}{k(k+1)}.
\end{align}

2) This is somewhat misleading. The $(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})$ does not become 1. Instead, most of the terms cancel with the $(\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+1})$ immediately after!

3) Here's how it works:
$$1-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Why could my brain not see that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{(2)(4)}+\frac{1}{(4)(6)}+\frac{1}{(6)(8)}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)2(n+1)}$

$\implies \frac{1}{2*2}[\frac{1}{(1)(2)}+\frac{1}{(2)(3)}+\frac{1}{(3)(4)}+...+\frac{1}{(n)(n+1)}]$

$\implies \frac{1}{4}[\frac{2-1}{(1)(2)}+\frac{3-2}{(2)(3)}+\frac{4-3}{(3)(4)}+...+\frac{(n+1)-n}{(n)(n+1)}]$

$\implies \frac{1}{4}[\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac 1 3 -\frac 1 4 + \cdots + \frac 1 n-\frac 1 {(n+1)}]$

Notice the alternate terms get cancelled out, except the first and the last terms.

$\implies \frac 1 4[1-\frac1 {n+1}]$

$\implies \frac n {4(n+1)}$